# Backbone error handling fetching multiple collections

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am fetching multiple collections in backbone using undescore's invoke method

```
var cols = [kf.Collections.invoices, kf.Collections.quotes, kf.Collections.bankaccounts, kf.Collections.invoicepaymentmethods];

var colsComplete = _.invoke(cols, 'fetch');
$.when.apply(null, colsComplete).then(callback);
```

Problem I'm facing is even if fetch to particular collection fails due to API error, it resumes fetching of remaining collections.

Is there any way I can stop fetching of other collections, if my API returns "UnAuthorized 401"?

Answer (score 1):

Fastest and simples solution for your problem can be implemented using the same underscore's `invoke` method to abort all promises in fail callback:

```
var cols = [kf.Collections.invoices, kf.Collections.quotes, kf.Collections.bankaccounts, kf.Collections.invoicepaymentmethods];

var colsComplete = _.invoke(cols, 'fetch');

$.when.apply(null, colsComplete).then(doneCallback, function () {
    _.invoke(colsComplete, 'abort'); 
});
```

This will call abort method on all promises. But I guess you don't need to call `abort` method on already failed promises or already finished requests.

In that case just check `readyState` of promise object and abort it depending on `readyState` value.